# Changing img src failing in IE?

Tags: jquery

I have the following line of code:

```
$( "img[title='my_image']" ).attr( "src", document.location.origin + "/reporter/content/images/ajax-loader.gif" );
```

Basically when the user clicks a button I want to display a progress indicator instead of the default image.

This works great in Chrome, but fails in IE and Firefox.  In those browsers, I just get the little broken image link icon.

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: what does `alert(document.location.origin + "/reporter/content/images/ajax-loader.gif");` in IE does?

Comment: `document.location.origin`?? How about `window.location.href`. If something doesn't work, start basic troubleshooting by logging the values you're using to the console.

Comment: @martriay Ah yep that's a problem.

Comment: @thesystem Yeah I kind of spaced on that- I got too complicated for no reason :).  Oh take that back.  So here's why I did this- the page is `http://localhost/site/pages/page.html`.  The IMAGE lives at `http://localhost/reporter/content/images/ajax-loader.gif`.  Document.location.origin gives the root url, window.location.href does not.  I need to find what gives `http://localhost` in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `document.location.origin`. Just by having `/` at the start of the new source, it will load relative to the current origin.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work- the image is not relative to the origin- its coming from a web.api app hosted at `http://localhost/reporter` this page is coming from `http://localhost`.

Comment: that doesn't matter.  they're still on the same domain ("origin"); the browser doesn't know or care about what apps are hosted where.

Comment: @Eevee You are right.  I was getting some strange behavior with this a bit ago- which is why I was using absolute url.